# How to run javascript function in web browser only when is not proccesing that function

Tags: javascript, performance, cross-browser

One of my javascript function is processing millions of data and it is called ~1 time every second from a hardware event. Then the web browser is idle in that function processing.

I tried to set a flag for running (or not running) that function:

```
if (!is_calculating)
    is_calculating = true;
else
    return;


my_function(); // do heavy stuff


is_calculating = false;
```

but it's not working, because it is entering into the code and the web browser enter in an idle status until is finishing. When it is returning, the flag is always OK, because it finished the *// do heavy stuff*

Can I do something for this behavior? I'd like to jump function execution if a flag is set.

Comment: Your problem is not clear.  How exactly is your function called "*~1 time every second*"?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I changed the code. It's called by a mobile GPS event.

Comment: Are you asking how to call your function *asynchronously*?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid the browser UI hanging and freezing due to the heavy calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, by default javascript runs in a single thread on browsers, so your code is executing completely before it even begins to process the next call, resulting in `is_calculating` always being false when the function is called. One workaround you could use (not the cleanest solution in the world), is to divide your monolithic 'heavy stuff' function into a number of smaller functions and have them call each other with `setTimeout(nextFunc, 1)`. Having them call each other that way gives the browser a moment to do what it needs to do, and additionally call your function again if that's what it's doing. This time, because your function is called in the 'middle' of it already being executed, `is_calculating` is still going to be true, and the call will return at the beginning like you expect it to. Note this solution probably isn't as preferable as the [Web Workers solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), but it is simpler.

```
function sleep(millis) {
  var date = new Date()
  var curDate = null
  do { curDate = new Date() }
  while(curDate-date < millis)
}

function reallyLong() {
  if(!reallyLong.flag) {
    reallyLong.flag = true
  } else {
    console.log("Not executing")
    return
  }

  sleep(250)
  setTimeout(reallyLong2, 1)

  function reallyLong2() {
    sleep(250)
    setTimeout(reallyLong3, 1)
  }

  function reallyLong3() {
    sleep(250)
    setTimeout(reallyLong4, 1)
  }

  function reallyLong4() {
    sleep(250)
    console.log("executed")
    reallyLong.flag = false
  }
}
```

If you define all your consecutive functions inside the primary function, it also allows them all to access the same data simply and easily.

The only catch now is if your function was returning some value, you need to rewrite it to either return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (Either of your own design or using a library like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)), or accept a callback as a parameter that the last function in the 'chain' will call with the return value as a parameter.

Note that the sleep function above is a hack, and awful, and terrible, and should never be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll think on this solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

By default JavaScript execution in browsers is not concurrent. This means, usually there can be only one currently executing piece of code.

You have to use [Web Workers API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to make you code run concurrently.